# International transit through Istanbul, and passport validity

Tags: air-travel, transit, uk-citizens, isl

I am a British citizen travelling from Dubai to Stansted with a stop in Istanbul. I will have 5 months validity on passport. Will this be acceptable. I am not leaving the airport.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=GB&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=GB&EM=AE&TR=TR&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C#) you're not required to have a visa given that you have a ticket to leave Turkey.

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Visa required, except for Holders of confirmed onward tickets
> for a max. transit For details, click here time of 24 hours.